# Android doesnt notice when i do an WWW-Authenticate

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, header, request

So my problem is the following:

I try do login to a website , which uses Basic Authentication (example picture:)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1DPt.png

The Authentication itself works, and i recieve the expected output as String via HTTPGet. But when i try to visit the site afterwards, using an intent like:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("Some Website"));
            handler.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

I get the window above shown again, which means, my phone doesnt know it has already been logged in.

So now is my question: How to save the information, that i have been logged in to the website? All i need to do is, to sumbit the Authorization Header so, that the Browser can recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use and save session cookies in your application .This can be achieved by saving your authentication cookies in shared preferences.For implementation look into cookie manager class in the developer page

Comment: Ive found this... http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/CookieManager.html#getCookieStore%28%29 If im right, i can put a requestHeader as cookie in there? Its a bit confusing, so i hope you can help with an example :/ Would appreciate it.

Comment: Again, hope you see... Can you tell me how, with an example? The documentation is quite confusing at this point...