# Login via Basic Authentication and open Browser afterwards

Tags: android, web, authentication

So I want to login to a webpage which uses Basic Authentication to login.

If I send HTTP Get with the Authorization Header, I get the successful response as HTML. But afterwards, it asks me again, to login, because it didn’t remember that I’m already logged in.

So my question is:

How can I save this information, that I have already been logged in?

I know, I already asked that question before, but since no one answered any more on the other thread my last hope was to open another.

The other thread: [Android doesnt notice when i do an WWW-Authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216288/android-doesnt-notice-when-i-do-an-www-authenticate)

---

EDIT:

So what i wanna do is:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("The Website with the Authentication")); // Here, i want to add the request header
        handler.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But i have no idea how, because, the only thing you can send the intent is the Url (and no request headers).

Hope this makes things clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Basic authentication doesn’t save state on the server end. Every request requires that you include the login information.

What happens normally is that:

1. The browser makes a request for a URL, lacking any authentication.
2. The server returns code 401, that this URL requires basic authentication.
3. The browser asks (either the user, or some database of its own) for the username and password. If it asked the user for the password, the browser then stores the username/password in an internal database, keying it against this URL.
4. For every further request for this URL, the browser includes that username and password in the HTTP GET request.

So the basic answer is, the server doesn’t remember that you have already logged in. The browser remembers that. Since you’re writing the browser, it’s up to you to have your application remember the username/password combination for that URL. Whatever you are doing now after you receive a 401 response, you simply always do for that URL. You don’t even need to wait for the 401 response.

Comment: I thought so. Any ideas how to add an Authorization Header to an Uri? Or how i can call any Browser with an Request Header?

Comment: In your question, you state that you can send HTTP Get with the Authorization header. That’s all you need to do. You just need to do it for every request.

Comment: The problem is, even if i do a HTTPGet via HTTPClient, it wont get noticed by the Browser. And in Android , you can open Browser just by an Intent . And the only parameter there is an Uri. So i have no idea where to put my Request Header in there... But anyway, already thanks for your responses.

Comment: You will want to clarify your question, then; as it stands, it sounds like you’re wanting to maintain authenticated requests after the first request. You might try using a numbered list to detail the steps you’re taking, and the responses you receive at each step that receives a response.

Comment: Edited the OP, hope you can understand now my question. I just simply want to add a Request Header when i open the Website in the Browser via the code shown above.